# Time single iteration of async for loop without global state

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to time, and record in the program, how long it takes to complete a single iteration of an async generator + for loop, without resorting to global state. For example, given

```
import asyncio

async def run():
    async for page in pull():
      await push(page)

async def pull():
  for i in range(0, 3):
    print(f'Start of iteration {i}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    yield i

async def push(i):
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print(f'End of iteration {i}')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

that outputs

```
Start of iteration 0
End of iteration 0
Start of iteration 1
End of iteration 1
Start of iteration 2
End of iteration 2
```

I would like to record the time between each `Start of iteration i` and the next `End of iteration i`.

How can this be done? Ideally without global state, and ideally where the timing code is somewhat decoupled from the rest (e.g. with decorators)

Comment: Could you use an async decorator to wrap the call?

Comment: Just an idea: use `logging` module and print log messages with time formatting inside?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I would like to keep a record of the times rather than print, and I think using the logging module is essentially the same as global state?

Comment: It was just an Idea (you can create MemoryHandler to log into memory also). Look at at @StephenRauch answer how to pass state between coroutines.

Comment: @janbernlöhr Decorators would be great. An issue however that I couldn’t quite get past is there isn’t a single function to decorate: each time has to cover “part” of a call to `pull` and then a single call to `push`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing around the `i` as an integer, you can pass a structure with some state.  Here is an example of augmenting the `i` with some timing information:

#### Timing info:

```
class TimerInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        my_int = super(TimerInt, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        my_int._start_time = time.time()
        return my_int

    @property
    def time_since_create(self):
        return time.time() - self._start_time
```

This gives the `int` a `time_since_create` property that can be used for some crude timing.

#### Test Code:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def run():
    async for page in pull():
        await push(page)

async def pull():
    for i in range(0, 3):
        i = TimerInt(i)
        print(f'Start of iteration {i}')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        yield i

async def push(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'End of iteration {i}: {i.time_since_create:.2f}')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

#### Test Results:

```
Start of iteration 0
End of iteration 0: 2.01
Start of iteration 1
End of iteration 1: 2.00
Start of iteration 2
End of iteration 2: 2.00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just care about the costed time, maybe you can calculate them in `run`. There is an example, I think it should work as if we just look at this `async for loop`, the process is lineal.

At first, `end - start` should equal to the time from the first iteration of `pull()` to the end of `push(page)`. And then use the `end` time as the second `start` time, so this time `end - start` should equal to the time from the second iteration of `pull()` to the end of `push(page)` again.

```
async def run():
    start = time.time()
    async for page in pull():
      await push(page)
      end = time.time()
      print("Cost {end - start} seconds")
      start = end
```

If I am wrong, correct me please.